# How to access Database which was in APP_DATA

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed a sample for membership and roles using the tutorial available. Now what i need is if i run my example in the other machine i would like to login and access the pages with the user name and password that were created using Asp.Net Configuration in my machine can any one give me an idea to achieve this

Comment: found it hard to understand what your problem is... but if by `run my example in the other machine` is meant how to access page you developed, go to `google.com` type `deploying asp.net website`, hit enter, read...

Comment: I know how to deploy a website

Comment: Specify more clearly what you need please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" /> 
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\App_Data\ASPNETDB.mdf;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

As per your need try this it will works

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```